# Is there a way to declare a type that depends on its sibling type

Tags: typescript

I’m trying to achieve something that might be an overkill but nice to have. I want to declare two parameters where one represents a `keyof` a **Model**, while the other represents whatever the type of that in a **Model** See the example below:

```js
interface Example<T> {
    key: keyof T;
    value: typeof T[key];
}
interface Test {
    first: string;
    second: number;
}
```

a correct value is:

```js
let test: Example<Test> = {
    key: “first”,
    value: “Hello world!”
};
```

An incorrect example would be:

```js
let test: Example<Test> = {
    key: “first”,
    value: 123
};
```

Is it possible to achieve such a thing with **Typescript**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, depending on what you are trying to do.

If you have a function and you need to enforce this on a parameter, we can do this using a generic type parameter:

```
interface Example<T, K extends keyof T> {
    key: K;
    value: T[K];
}
function withProp<T>(){
  return function<K extends keyof T>(value: Example<T, K>) {

  }
}

let test= withProp<Test>()({
    key: "first",
    value: "Hello world!"
});

// Error
let test2 = withProp<Test>()({
    key: "first",
    value: 123
});
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5mQbwFDKHIzBRYBcyWUoA5gNwFEYQID2IAJpSAK4C2AI2iMAvnlCRYiFAFEAHnH4AHADYQAPKgA0yANLII8yFwzIA1hACebGGgB8uJoUtXKexkWQA3OKt4QlKgA2noAumJ4MLwgCGDAHMgA7sBgABYAClBsylr2ABQAlPiEUBBgvFAgxDFxCSAaBkYmnGautg75vv6ByApKapo6+vaFTkzi4njq2JBYALzJqZnZuehYBYX5JUSulABEJGRg+9rOPn4BBwASEKqqbMlsUKqcAIT7eKKFjHgA9H8+lBslBpuVkHMwAAmZCLFLpLI5LSYMCbbbnPbIQ6kLCnc7dK7IACMUIAzF8fkA)

If you want to enforce this on a random variable, you can use a mapped type to generate all possible combinations of key-type as a union:

```
type Example<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: {
      key: K;
      value: T[K];
  }
}[keyof T]

let test: Example<Test> = {
    key: "first",
    value: "Hello world!"
};

// Error
let test2: Example<Test> = {
    key: "first",
    value: 123
}
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgQwLZgDYQDwBUB8UC8UA3gFBRQDaA0lAJYB2UA1hCAPYBmUWAugFzEy5YSxACqAbiHCoANwSoArhAFZqPKeQC+JLRVGduPEiQbAIAJw4IAxtCwQAzsEEyOtC84HOLDAOaawo4QNmz0ACYC9IpIAEaWUjok6C7mXrCIKOjYTsB4hKQyogIARO6ewCUANNJyCsqlABIQqKhsUADubBao4QCEJbpSJAD0I7AWFt3JEKm5AEwC8MhomA7O+a4irKXlztW18koqUACM8wDMukA)

Answer (score 0):

This may help you ([live demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIA84FsAOAbCAHgBUAaZAaWQnUhABMBnZAawgE8B7GZYgPmQBvALAAoZMgBucPAFcIALl4BtCgF0A3GIC+Y0JFiIUxCIzBCxEmMChmlZqKADmW8ckYQEnBkpCysAEbQrrqiYtJQyNa2YEoY2PhEJmbkAETRZql8rhlgAHTSchAayAD0pe5gjiBOYuFwkR5ePmiYuAQkpmBpTd70Wa69DAUy8iXlyH6B0GJAA)):

```
interface Example<T, K extends keyof T> {
  value: T[K];
}
interface Test {
  first: string;
  second: number;
}

var first: Example<Test, "first">;
first.value; // string

var second: Example<Test, "second">;
second.value; // number
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be close enough:

```
interface Example<T, K extends keyof T> {
    key: K;
    value: T[K];
}
interface Test {
    first: string;
    second: number;
}
const ok1 : Example<Test, "first"> = {
    key: "first",
    value: "s",
}
const ok2 : Example<Test, "second"> = {
    key: "second",
    value: 12,
}
const error1 : Example<Test, "first"> = {
    key: "first",
    value: 12,
}
```